# how to fetch Object id from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to fetch document from mongoDB using python i am able to fetch all attribute but i just wanted to fetch its object id and store it into a variable .

i am trying following code

```
from pymongo import Connection
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


connection = Connection()
server="localhost"
port = 27017

connection =Connection(server , port)

db = connection.flipkart

connection = db.flipitems

connection.remove({'name':None})

for post in connection.find():
    print post['_id':'ObjectId']
    seller_name = post['seller_name']
    name = post['name']
```

but it gives following error

> shubham@shubham-pc:~/Desktop/python$ python fetch_data.py  Traceback
>
> (most recent call last):   File "fetch_data.py", line 18, in
>
> ```
> print post['_id':'ObjectId'] TypeError: unhashable type
> ```

Comment: what gives you if you `print post`?

Comment: Do you want it as objectId or a string?

Comment: then it gives the whole document (Row) with id

Comment: try `print post[id]` or `print post[_id]`

Comment: @ArunK i want to use it again as comparison with id for updating document . so which one is better  string or ObjectId ?

Comment: @bigOTHER  thanks its working

Comment: @Shubhambatra : Object Id would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
    print str(post['_id'])
```

This will give the ObjectId in string format

`print post['_id']` will return the objectId as ObjectId('123456789023456') itself

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in `post['_id':'ObjectId']`, you should do either:

```
print post['_id']
```

or

```
print post['ObjectId']
```